# Disable 'Leave Site?' question when using ContentTools

Tags: javascript, content-tools

I'm using [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com/) free WYSIWYG editor.

I've modified the code so that the form does not save async but inline with the form and submits the page, like a regular HTML form.

To do this, I've modified the save function (given on the tutorials page) from this:

```
// Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
payload = new FormData();
for (name in regions) {
    if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        payload.append(name, regions[name]);
    }
}
```

To this:

```
var $form = document.getElementById("form-contenttools")
if($form.length) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    var hiddeninput = document.createElement("INPUT")
    hiddeninput.setAttribute("type","hidden")
    hiddeninput.setAttribute("name","document")
    hiddeninput.setAttribute("value",regions[0])

    var form_submit_flag = document.createElement("INPUT")
    form_submit_flag.setAttribute("type","hidden")
    form_submit_flag.setAttribute("name","contenttools_form_submit")
    form_submit_flag.setAttribute("value",true)

    $form.append(hiddeninput)
    $form.append(form_submit_flag)

    editor.busy(false);
    new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
    $form.submit();
}
```

However, I've still get the alert message 'Leave site? Any changes you made will not be saved' after clicking the save button.  To combat this I put the line `window.onbeforeunload = null;` In to the javascript (in various places) but this doesnt seem to be taking affect.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm approaching a point where I'll need to do that too, if no solution is found, I'll look into it myself too.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = null;
This can be used to subscribe or unsubscribe to the event. But you decided to not register (null) to the event. But this will not clear any already registered events.

Comment: @Adriani6 I think I have found the solution, I'll add it tomorrow when I'm back in the office

Comment: @Chud37 Nice one, really helpful if you do share (save me some work on our CMS system).

Comment: @Adriani6 The creator responded on GitHub, the correct way is `window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', editor._handleBeforeUnload);` just after `editor.ignition().edit();` (If you choose to do what I'm doing in the above question)

Comment: @Chud37 Thanks a lot for getting back on this one. Really appreciate the effort :)